# Simple proof solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \geq 2$, prove that $n^2 + 1 > 2n -1$.

Comment: This isn't true: take $n = 5$, for example.

Comment: Better yet, try $n=2$.

Comment: I think the inequality sign is the other way around...

Comment: Yes, inequality is in the other direction ...
What did you try?

Comment: Am newbie to both this site and question topic. But was amazed how quickly you guys responded.

Comment: It looks like a grade 9 algebra question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the inequality is wrong.  The problem should read $n^2+1\gt 2n-1$

Proof is trivial: Statement is equivalent to $n^2-2n+2=(n-1)^2+1\gt 0$ which is obvious.

Comment: Can you pls explain step by step

Comment: Start with $n^2+1\gt 2n-1$  Subtract $2n-1$ from both sides to get $n^2-2n+2\gt 0$ Note that $n^2-2n+1=(n-1)^2$ to get final result.

Comment:  get it now.n